# How to adding a delay before the Countdowntimer starts?

Tags: android, kotlin, countdowntimer

I'm trying to add a 2 second delay without locking the main thread every time a resume is called in the countdown timer. Without adding a delay, this below works perfectly, but when I add a delay, the main thread hangs. Every time I call resume and add delay with sendmessage delay, the thread hang. How can I add a 2 second delay just every time a resume is called without breaking the main timer ?

```
    abstract class CountDownTimer(
    /**
     * Real time remaining until timer completes
     */
    private var mMillisInFuture: Long,
    countDownInterval: Long,
    runAtStart: Boolean,
) {

    private var delayT: Long = 2000

    /**
     * Millis since boot when alarm should stop.
     */
    private var mStopTimeInFuture: Long = 0

    /**
     * Total time on timer at start
     */
    private var mTotalCountdown: Long = mMillisInFuture

    /**
     * The interval in millis that the user receives callbacks
     */
    private var mCountdownInterval: Long = 0

    /**
     * The time remaining on the timer when it was paused, if it is currently paused; 0 otherwise.
     */
    private var mPauseTimeRemaining: Long = 0

    /**
     * True if timer was started running, false if not.
     */
    private val mRunAtStart: Boolean

    /**
     * Cancel the countdown and clears all remaining messages
     */
    fun cancel() {
        mHandler.removeMessages(MSG)
    }

    /**
     * Create the timer object.
     */
    @Synchronized
    fun create(): CountDownTimer {
        if (mMillisInFuture <= 0) {
            onFinish()
        } else {
            mPauseTimeRemaining = mMillisInFuture
        }
        if (mRunAtStart) {
            resume()
        }
        return this
    }

    /**
     * Pauses the counter.
     */
    fun pause() {
        if (isRunning) {
            mPauseTimeRemaining = timeLeft()
            cancel()
        }
    }

    /**
     * Resumes the counter.
     */
    fun resume() {
        if (isPaused) {
            mMillisInFuture = mPauseTimeRemaining
            mStopTimeInFuture = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + mMillisInFuture
            mHandler.sendMessage(mHandler.obtainMessage(MSG))
            mPauseTimeRemaining = 0
        }
    }

    /**
     * Tests whether the timer is paused.
     *
     * @return true if the timer is currently paused, false otherwise.
     */
    val isPaused: Boolean
        get() = mPauseTimeRemaining > 0

    /**
     * Tests whether the timer is running. (Performs logical negation on [.isPaused])
     *
     * @return true if the timer is currently running, false otherwise.
     */
    val isRunning: Boolean
        get() = !isPaused

    /**
     * Returns the number of milliseconds remaining until the timer is finished
     *
     * @return number of milliseconds remaining until the timer is finished
     */
    fun timeLeft(): Long {
        var millisUntilFinished: Long
        if (isPaused) {
            millisUntilFinished = mPauseTimeRemaining
        } else {
            millisUntilFinished = mStopTimeInFuture - SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()
            if (millisUntilFinished < 0) millisUntilFinished = 0
        }
        return millisUntilFinished
    }

    /**
     * Returns the number of milliseconds in total that the timer was set to run
     *
     * @return number of milliseconds timer was set to run
     */
    fun totalCountdown(): Long {
        return mTotalCountdown
    }

    fun setTotalCountdown(millis: Long) {
        mTotalCountdown += millis
    }

    /**
     * Returns the number of milliseconds that have elapsed on the timer.
     *
     * @return the number of milliseconds that have elapsed on the timer.
     */
    fun timePassed(): Long {
        return mTotalCountdown - timeLeft()
    }

    /**
     * Returns true if the timer has been started, false otherwise.
     *
     * @return true if the timer has been started, false otherwise.
     */
    fun hasBeenStarted(): Boolean {
        return mPauseTimeRemaining <= mMillisInFuture
    }

    /**
     * Callback fired on regular interval
     *
     * @param millisUntilFinished The amount of time until finished
     */
    abstract fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long)

    /**
     * Callback fired when the time is up.
     */
    abstract fun onFinish()

    // handles counting down
    private val mHandler: Handler = object : Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()) {
        override fun handleMessage(msg: Message) {
            synchronized(this@CountDownTimer) {
                val millisLeft = timeLeft()
                if (millisLeft <= 0) {
                    cancel()
                    onFinish()
                } else if (millisLeft < mCountdownInterval) {
                    // no tick, just delay until done
                    sendMessageDelayed(obtainMessage(MSG), millisLeft)
                } else {
                    val lastTickStart = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()
                    onTick(millisLeft)
                    // take into account user's onTick taking time to execute
                    var delay =
                        mCountdownInterval - (SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - lastTickStart)

                    // special case: user's onTick took more than mCountdownInterval to
                    // complete, skip to next interval
                    while (delay < 0) delay += mCountdownInterval
                    sendMessageDelayed(obtainMessage(MSG), delay)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    companion object {
        private const val MSG = 1
        private const val MSG2 = 2
    }

    /**
     * @param //millisInFuture  The number of millis in the future from the call
     * to [//start][.] until the countdown is done and [.onFinish]
     * is called
     * @param countDownInterval The interval in millis at which to execute
     * [//#onTick(millisUntilFinished)][//.onTick] callbacks
     * @param runAtStart        True if timer should start running, false if not
     */
    init {
        mCountdownInterval = countDownInterval
        mRunAtStart = runAtStart
    }
}
```

Comment: What purpose you're using like that...

Comment: based on user choices i need something like this

Comment: I can't get you. Delay based what you will do?

Comment: delay will be like giving 2 seconds extra when resume is called but it won't be added to the main time just like 2 seconds advance and then start.  I don't know how to explain more

Comment: I'm asking business logic... Why you're delaying... What was the user experience?

Comment: Ooo I now undestand sorry. In fact, the user chooses this on purpose, so let the time begin, but delay it by 2  or 10 seconds, but don't show me that 2  or 10 seconds and i can stop the countdown timer if i want when this is waiting

Comment: Countdowntimer works in main thread. Remove your handler use interface. No need handler..

Comment: You can use lifecycleScope delay then start countdown timer

Comment: This isn't the Android CountDownTimer class, so a Handler is needed to run the behavior.